# Is there an efficient way to add multiple Appinks to mobile devices in HTML?

Tags: android, html, ios, deep-linking, applinks

I am a developer of a basic e-commerce app which has a companion website. I wanted to try app links as a way to direct my users from my website to certain screens on my mobile app.

The applinks website [tutorial](http://applinks.org/documentation/) gives the following example as a way to introduce app links to a certain app.

This is possible if I wanted to "link" to just one screen in each app. But what do I have to do if I want to link to multiple screens?

I want the website to be able to direct the user to the home screen, the search screen as well as the payment screen. Is there an efficient way to do this? Do I have to add different app links on different pages?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the response Alex. I've tried to follow your guide for my Android app but it doesn't seem to work. Whenever I open the URL of my website on the Android Chrome browser nothing happens. I want an automatic redirect to my app.
This is a snippet of my code (under pseudonyms for the names and urls).

Website:

```
     <meta property="al:android:url" content="ecommerceapp://dlogsman" />
     <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ECommerceApp" />
     <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.ecommerce.app" />
     <meta property="al:web:url" content="http://ecommerce.com/~dlogsman" />
```

Android Manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.ecommerce.app.App"
        android:label="@string/app_name_ecommerce">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="ecommerceapp" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And then my onStart method handles the intent exactly like you recommended. Any suggestions?? Thanks again for the time.

Answer (score 0):

As a heads up, I work on the Branch linking tool ([branch.io](https://branch.io)) which helps simplify deep linking across all channels including Facebook (and simplifying the AppLinks nightmare)

What App Links do is simply tell the Facebook robot how to map a corresponding website URL to your native app URL. It's just a set of metatags to add to your site's header in order to tell Facebook which app URL to call when the app is installed. *The only actual link is your website link*. Therefore, you can only have 1 set of AppLinks on a given page on your existing ecommerce site. In order to use AppLinks to different pages in your app, you'll need to actually have different web URLs. So, you'll need to have a:

- `http://yourecommercesite.com/home` and add metatags for `yourecommerceapp://home`
- `http://yourecommercesite.com/search` and add metatags for `yourecommerceapp://search`
- `http://yourecommercesite.com/payment` and add metatags for `yourecommerceapp://payment`

Then, you'll need to structure your app for deep linking. In case you haven't done that, here's how to set it up and receive the URL path in iOS:

1. Add the URI scheme for yourecommerceapp:// to the PLIST file

[image: plist uri]

2. Write the code to receive the URI path

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[url path] hasSuffix:@"home"]) {
        // load the home view controller
    } else if ([[url path] hasSuffix:@"search"]) {
        // load the search view controller
    } else if ([[url path] hasSuffix:@"payment"]) {
        // load the payment view controller
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And here's how in Android:

1. Setup the app Manifest to receive intents from yourecommercesite://. You just need to add this inside the `<activity></activity>` tags

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="yourecommercesite"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

2. In onStart of the Activity that receives the intent, add the following code:

```java
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (this.getIntent().getData() != null) {
        if (this.getIntent().getData().getPath().equals("home")) {
            // load the home activity
        } else if (this.getIntent().getData().getPath().equals("search")) {
            // load the search activity
        } else if (this.getIntent().getData().getPath().equals("payment")) {
            // load the payment activity
        }
    }

}
```